# Android Invisible CustomView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

I've created a custom `RelativeLayout` that has two `ImageView` in it, one on top of the other, The first one is supposed to show the user selected image and the second on is shown up after he selected and acts as a delete button (small X icon), the problem that i have is even at the start of the application this custom view is invisible, but i can still click on it. and if i use a background for it i can see it.
Here is my Custom View class and XML

```
 public class ImageViewWithIcon extends RelativeLayout{
    public ImageView      image, icon;
    private final Context context;

    public ImageViewWithIcon(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ImageViewWithIcon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view_with_icon, this, true);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) getChildAt(0);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewWithIcon_icon);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewWithIcon_image);
        // image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(400, 400));
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ImageViewWithIcon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_message_picture_button);
        int width;
        if (getLayoutParams().width == android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            width = bmp.getWidth();
        else
            if (getLayoutParams().width == android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT || getLayoutParams().width == android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)
                width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            else
                width = getLayoutParams().width;
        int height = 100;
        if (getLayoutParams().height == android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            height = bmp.getHeight();
        else
            if (getLayoutParams().height == android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT || getLayoutParams().height == android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)
                height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            else
                height = getLayoutParams().height;
        bmp.recycle();
        setMeasuredDimension(width | MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, height | MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }}


<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageViewWithIcon_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/new_message_picture_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageViewWithIcon_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ImageViewWithIcon_image"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/new_message_close_picture"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

The first line in `onMessure` has bmp with width and height of 234px

even if I create a method like `setImage()` to call it from the `Activity`, the image is set but it is still invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageViewWithIcon
                android:id="@+id/ImageViewWithIcon_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/new_message_picture_button" />

            <ImageViewWithIcon
                android:id="@+id/ImageViewWithIcon_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ImageViewWithIcon_image"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:src="@drawable/new_message_close_picture"/>
```

Comment: No, the XML that I posted is the ImageViewWithIcon XML, inside of it there are tow regular ImageViews.

Comment: Probably in your onMeasure method - widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec is 0. Because your RelativeLayout have wrap_content, but it is have not content when onMeasure is called.

Comment: the widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec is the same size of the bitmap size, in this case is 234 px, and if I use the background property for that view in the MainActiviry.XML I can see it.